# How to do a multi-row multi-drop down form with one submit button?

Tags: php, html

**I am trying to create a program that allows a user to input a list of names (into a form).**

**On the next page, pulling through the values created by the form, users select from a series of dropdowns,  choosing either 'excellent', 'good', or 'poor' for three different categories (performance, effort, attendance) for each name.**

Once all of the dropdowns have had selections made, the user submits the form.

So far, I have a couple of input boxes that allows users to input the names ($name0, and $name2).

```
<form action="form_action.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name0"><br />
<br />
Name: <input type="text" name="name1"><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This data is then displayed in its most basic form.

```
<?php echo $_POST["name0"]; ?><br>
  <br />
 <?php echo $_POST["name1"]; ?>
```

I know my code is about as basic as it can be at the moment, but I basically need to now add a load of different dropdown boxes that allow the users to make selections for each person on the list.

Comment: You have already created a multi input form. Try `<select><option></option></select>` to get dropdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first form, you can change the name of your inputs to `names[]`, which will then make the names available as an array in `$_POST['names']` in `form_action.php`.

```
<form action="form_action.php" method="post">
    <label>Name 1<input name="names[]"></label>
    <label>Name 2<input name="names[]"></label>
</form>
```

Then in your `form_action.php`, you can simply do a foreach loop over the names array.

```
<form action="submit_ratings.php" method="post">
<?php foreach ($_POST['names'] as $name): ?>
    <h2>Rate <?= $name ?></h2>

    <!-- hidden input to pass along name to next step -->
    <input type="hidden" name="names[]" value="<?= $name ?>">
    <select name="performance[]">
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good" selected>Good</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    </select>
    <select name="effort[]">
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good" selected>Good</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    </select>

<?php endforeach ?>
</form>
```

If you entered "Bob" and "Ted" as the names, the PHP above would generate this HTML:

```
<form action="submit_ratings.php" method="post">
    <h2>Rate Bob</h2>

    <!-- hidden input to pass along name to next step -->
    <input type="hidden" name="names[]" value="Bob">
    <select name="performance[]">
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good" selected>Good</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    </select>
    <select name="effort[]">
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good" selected>Good</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    </select>

    <h2>Rate Ted</h2>

    <!-- hidden input to pass along name to next step -->
    <input type="hidden" name="names[]" value="Ted">
    <select name="performance[]">
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good" selected>Good</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    </select>
    <select name="effort[]">
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good" selected>Good</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

Upon submitting this generated form, the `submit_ratings.php` script would then receive three arrays in `$_POST`: `names`, `performance`, and `effort`.  You could then display them like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Performance</th>
            <th>Effort</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($_POST['names'] as $index => $name): ?>
         <tr>
             <td><?= $name ?></td>
             <td><?= $_POST['performance'][$index] ?></td>
             <td><?= $_POST['effort'][$index] ?></td>
         </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

One advantage of this approach is that on your first form, you could have an any number of `name="names[]"` inputs, and all of the subsequent steps will still work.

Comment: This is kind of an old-school approach, though.  You should really be using JavaScript to add rows to your form dynamically and submitting everything at once.

Comment: Thanks @jpec, your answer was very useful and works very well.
It's also given me plenty to go away and practice with. I'll certainly look into Javascript in order to future-proof my code.

Comment: The only part of your code that I'm unsure of (I don't perfectly understand it) is:
     <?php foreach ($_POST['names'] as $index => $name): ?>

I understand that this will iterate through each item within the $name array. But what does the $index => $name section mean?

Comment: In a `foreach()`, you can get either just the value of the item from the array, or both the key and value.  The PHP documentation explains it better than I can: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php